# after a button displays items using for loop, how to sum listbox items on C#

Tags: c#

Hi I have a button that displays results using for loop, I want to find the sum of all the numbers and write them into the textBox2. I don't know how to do it. I'm using Visual Studio 2012, .NET 4.5 Framework. Your help is appreciated. Thanks.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         for (int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++)
            if (i % 21 == 0 || i % 5 == 0)
                {
                    listBox2.Items.Add(i);
                }
         int sum = ??????? ;
         textBox2.Text = sum.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Andre, I have read this question before but this is a completely different case.

Answer (score 4):

I think this might be what you're looking for.

```
foreach(int i in listBox2.Items) {
    sum += i;
}
```

However, if the list box is empty before this button click, try:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     int sum = 0;
     for (int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++)
        if (i % 21 == 0 || i % 5 == 0)
            {
                sum += i;
                listBox2.Items.Add(i);
            }
     textBox2.Text = sum.ToString();
}
```

Comment: thank you! never thought about that way. I Added the missing "0" to the code and the problem is solved!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply find the sum when You add the items.

```
int sum=0;
for (int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++)
            if (i % 21 == 0 || i % 5 == 0)
                {
                    listBox2.Items.Add(i);
                    sum+=i;
                }
         textBox2.Text = sum.ToString();
```